# Auto-disable Wi-Fi AP if not connected within a few minutes?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

Is there any way for me to make my phone automatically disable its Wi-Fi Access Point and re-enable its Wi-Fi client when no client has connected to the access point after (say) 5 minutes?

Comment: I cannot say I could see this occurring without Root permissions. I know there are apps like Tasker and AutoMateIt where you can turn WiFi off when not connected, but WiFi hotspot on AND off depending on usage may be extending it's capabilities. Phone Model, Android Version and Rooted or not?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow: It's a OnePlus One, and yes it is rooted. I don't have the *exact* version number, but it's a 4.4 KitKat.

Comment: I think the best possibility here is Tasker, or some similar tasking function. I've never tried the WiFi hotspot function. I am not too aware of other possibilities.

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow: I've tried it, but Tasker doesn't let me check the AP status.

Comment: To be honest without even looking into this, I would assume that one would need root permission for this process- if it could even be achieved.

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow: Yeah, like I said I have root permissions so that is not a problem.